# Matrix with arrows

Tags: matrices, arrows

How can I create such a matrix with arrows in Latex?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To the close-voters: wait a few days before closing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSY4.png. 
Let's give the OP time to refine his/her question!

Comment: I feel like we've had this before...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully automatized constructions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\NM{5}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1.5ex,row sep=1.5ex,
nodes in empty cells,
cells={nodes={
execute at begin node={%
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<\NM
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow<\NM
$a_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$
\fi
\else
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow<\NM
$\cdots$
\else
$\ddots$
\fi
\fi
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\NM
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<\NM
$\vdots$
\fi
\fi
}}},
execute at end matrix={%
\foreach \X in {2,...,\the\numexpr\NM-1\relax}
{
\ifodd\X
 \draw[-latex] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr\X-1\relax-1)
  --
  (\tikzmatrixname-\X-1);
\else
 \draw[-latex] (\tikzmatrixname-1-\the\numexpr\X-1\relax)
  --
  (\tikzmatrixname-1-\X);
\fi
\foreach \Y in {2,...,\X}
 {\ifodd\X
  \draw[latex-] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr1+\Y-2\relax-\the\numexpr\X-\Y+2\relax)
  --
  (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr2+\Y-2\relax-\the\numexpr\X-\Y+1\relax);
 \else
  \draw[-latex] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr1+\Y-2\relax-\the\numexpr\X-\Y+2\relax)
  --
  (\tikzmatrixname-\the\numexpr2+\Y-2\relax-\the\numexpr\X-\Y+1\relax);
 \fi}
}}]{
 & & & & \\ 
 & & & &\\ 
 & & & &\\ 
 & & & &\\ 
 & & & &\\ 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]